# How does one have the vscode debugger halt even inside a try catch in python?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Seeing the questions that are suggested as "similar" it seems most people want the opposite of what I want. What I want is that the debugger for Vs-code halts at the point of error even if inside a try catch (as it would usually do).

But instead what it does is not halt when inside a try catch like this one:

```
import traceback 

try:
    main() # has bugs I'm trying to debug
except Exception as e:
    send_email(traceback.format_exc())
    send_email(e)
```

I understand that this might be a weird thing to want & that vs-code's debugger is probably acting correctly (since my code it's telling it how to handle exceptions!) but I am having bugs that I want to debug rather to catch. In fact my outer try catch is just there because I am using a cluster that sends me emails when there is any bug and tells me about them. Otherwise I would not have a try catch at all around my main code.

Is there a way to tell vs-code to ignore my try catches when I am actually debugging?

---

An idea I just had as I was writing this was to change the sort of exceptions I catch...though during debugging I want it to always halt and when not debugging I want it to never halt and send me an e-mail with the bug.

Any ideas?

---

New error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

when using my `EmptyException` answer:

```
class EmptyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: A little bit confused. Do you mean even tho you set breakpoint inside try catch, it is not working? (or) Do you want to halt at error without setting breakpoint? If it is former, it is working correctly in my vscode. I mean it halt inside try catch. But if it is latter, you can tick "Raised Exceptions" checkbox in Debugger -> Breakpoints tab. It will halt at the line that raised Exception even without breakpoint.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a really dumb way to do it but when I running in debugging mode I have a flag that is set to true:

```
args.debug = True
```

then based on that flag I set the type of exception:

```
if args.debug:
    args.ExceptionType = Exception
else:
    args.ExceptionType = EmptyError
```

where `EmptyError` is a custom exception that doesn't do anything, it's just so that VS-code halts when I am running in debugging mode:

```
class EmptyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Sort of dumb but I don't know anything better.

Comment: I just put a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` just before the line where I need debugger to stop i.e the breakpoint. Before this change debugger was not stopping. After this it stopped at every breakpoint. I was using visual studio for mac . It is a c# (.net core) project